# Get position while matching pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, pattern-matching, filtering

I want following imaginary feature : `PositionOf`

Example1)

```
In[1]  Cases[{3,5,1,7,2,8,9,7,5,6}, x_ /; x > 4 :> PositionOf[x]]

Out[1]  {2,4,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Above code extracts elements bigger than 4 (`x_ /; x > 4`),
{5,7,8,9,7,5,6}
and produce their position `:> PositionOf[x]`:
{2,4,6,7,8,9,10}

Example2)

```
In[2]  Cases[{3,5,1,7,2,8,9,7,5,6}, x_ /; x + PositionOf[x] == 14]

Out[2]  {8,5}
```

Above code extracts every element x such that
x + its position is 14 (`x_ /;x + PositionOf[x] == 14`)
In the list, 8 is 6th, and 5 is 9th. 8+6 = 5+9 = 14.
So the output is {8,5}.

There is a code that works for example 1 :

```
Flatten[Position[{3,5,1,7,2,8,9,7,5,6}, x_ /; x > 4 ]]
```

also for example 2 by indexing method (using Range,Length,Transpose,Part.)

But I am curious that PositionOf[x] like feature is ever possible. If there is no such thing, a slight variation is also welcomed.

Comment: `Position` already has this capability for your first example: `Flatten[Position[{3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6}, x_ /; x > 4]]` returns `{2,4,6,7,8,9,10}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example 1 already addressed in the comments as position can already handle this.

Example 2 is addressed below:

```
With[{list = {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6}},
  Select[14 == Plus @@ # &][Thread[{list, Range@Length@list}]]
 ][[All, 1]]
(* returns : {8, 5} *)
```

Another way using [`ResourceFunction["PositionCases"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PositionCases/):

```
PositionCases = ResourceFunction["PositionCases"];
PositionCases[{3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6}, 
 PositionPattern[pos_, x_] /; pos != {} && First[pos] + x == 14]
(* returns : {8, 5} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6};

Cases[MapIndexed[List] @ list, {a_, {b_}} /; a + b == 14 -> a]
```

{8, 5}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6};
```

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
GroupBy[Thread[{#, Range@Length@#}] &@list, Total@# == 14 &, First /@ # &][True]

(*{8, 5}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6};
Pick[a, MapIndexed[#1 + #2[[1]] &, a], 14]
```

yields {8,5}

Or:

```
Pick[a, 14 - a - Range[Length[a]], 0]
```

Comment: Or more briefly, `Pick[a, MapIndexed[Plus, a], {14}]` (+1)

Comment: @Goofy yes indeed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is concerned only with the index at level 1 and not with general positions. Here is another solution to example 2 along those lines:

```
{3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6} //
 Module[{idx = 0}, Cases[#, x_ /; ++idx + x == 14]] &

(* {8, 5} *)
```